# What is the event's name?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

**Question.** What is the event's name?

Answer is the word.

Hint 1

> After the nonogram one should find Braille symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I got for solving the nonogram:

> [image]

Then did this:

> Got the braille characters [image]

then my answer was:

> (Using Unicode - "sgznlkyz")

Then the final step is

> Using Caesar Cipher (shifted by +6)
>  That gets you the answer "mathfest"

Comment: you are right, but nonogram is one step here only.

Comment: I tried morse code but it didn't work...

Comment: I added the hint 1.

Comment: Thanks, I think that the hint is too obvious, I suggested an edit to the hint

Comment: Your answer is correct to where you are at now.  There's one more step.

Comment: @amitklein, positions of Braille symbols were defined correctly.

Comment: I recommend you try rot-20 (Caesar shift)...

Comment: I think I got it, thanks